# Win32_OperatingSytem Shutdown method; script returning error code 80041021

Tags: methods, vbscript

I'm trying to write a script capable of shutting down a local computer even if the computer is locked. I'm trying to invoke the shutdown method of the Win32_OperatingSystem class. I've read this article: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_cpm_evqo.mspx and it still won't work. I've even tried copying and pasting the code provided in the article. It still won't work. Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is a syntax error with `Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts: {(Shutdown)}" _`...

Should be as follows:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" _
 & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax was the issue. However, the script still will not shutdown the computer if the computer is locked. But at least I got this one problem figured out.

Comment: @Adam: _script capable of shutting down a local computer even if the computer is locked_. How do you launch the script? Remote? Or scheduled?

Comment: Scheduled. I was considering doing it remotely. But I never got around to implementing that.The biggest issue I'm having is that the script is running on a separate desktop from the lock screen. And I can't switch to a secure desktop. So running it remotely might possibly make that work. Though it is unlikely.

Comment: @Adam: in my humble opinion, this should be asked at [Super User](http://superuser.com/). However, instead WMI, did you try [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) by Sysinternals?

Comment: I have not tried using PsShutdown for it. It didn't even cross my mind to try PsTools for this. I thought it would be simple enough to get it working with Microsoft's provided COM objects and methods. But it seems I may need to turn elsewhere for this project. Thanks for the suggestions!